# MySql SELECT query

Tags: php, sql

I am writing a script that calculates a Kill-Death Ratio (KDR) based on values obtained from a MySQL table. I am fixing somebody else's code. I have managed to get most of it working again. However, I have got stuck here. The KDR is calculated by adding all the kills, and dividing by the number of deaths of the player. But, if the player has never died, then the KDR comes out at 0. I need a way to read the 0, as a 1 when evaluating the KDR. I did google this, and tried to write a UDF I could use, but alas it did not help.

Below is the SQL query in question

```
function get_leaders($civ, $neu, $riv){
    $sSQL = "SELECT *, ((civilian_kills * _civ + neutral_kills * _neu + rival_kills * _riv) / deaths ) as KDR
              from sc_players
              order by KDR DESC
              LIMIT 100;";
```

Comment: You could write a MySQL Function to do that for you, or just do it in PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

```
SELECT *,
IF(deaths,civilian_kills * $civ + neutral_kills * $neu + rival_kills * $riv) / deaths,1) as KDR
from sc_players
order by KDR DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: wouldn't it be `SELECT *, IF(deaths==0,1,((civilian_kills * $civ + neutral_kills * $neu + rival_kills * $riv) / deaths))`

Comment: yes, it would. For some reason I wasn't thinking in terms of ratios, good catch.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean the divisor should be treated as 1 when it is 0. In that case, you would do

```
SELECT *, ((civilian_kills * $civ + neutral_kills * $neu + rival_kills * $riv) / 
    (IF deaths = 0 THEN 1 ELSE deaths)
) as KDR from sc_players order by KDR DESC LIMIT 100;
```

Assuming deaths is nonnegative, you could also do:

```
SELECT *, ((civilian_kills * $civ + neutral_kills * $neu + rival_kills * $riv) / 
    GREATEST(deaths, 1)
) as KDR from sc_players order by KDR DESC LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: You had the same initial understanding as I did in my solution, but if you give it a bit more thought - the KDR is the ratio of kills to deaths. If you treat the denominator as a 1 instead of a 0, you end up returning the number of kills the player has rather than the 100% ratio of kills to deaths as expected.

Comment: If you look at the original query in the case when deaths is positive, the answer is greater than 1 if the player has more kills than deaths, so I don't think you'd want to return 1 for someone who has never died.

Comment: True. I suppose what he wants is the average of kills per death, in which case your solution would be the correct one.